# Why is my div not returning to normal when my mouse leaves the area?

Tags: jquery, mouseenter, mouseleave

I'm using some javascript to increase the size of a div when a mouse enters the target area, but then I want it to return to normal size when the mouse leaves the targeted area.

Not sure what is wrong with my code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".someContent").on("mouseenter", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("highLight");
    if ($(this).hasClass('highLight')) {
    $(this).animate({"width": "80%", "height": "200px", "opacity": "1"}, "fast");
} else {
    $(this).animate({"width": "30%", "height": "60px", "opacity": "1"}, "fast");
}
$(".someContent").on("mouseleave", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("highLight");
});
});
})
```

I have it working now with

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".someContent").on("mouseenter", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("highLight");
    if ($(this).hasClass('highLight')) {
        $(this).animate({"width": "80%", "height": "200px", "opacity": "1"}, "fast");
    } else {
        $(this).animate({"width": "30%", "height": "60px", "opacity": "1"}, "fast");
    }
}).on("mouseleave", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("highLight");
});
})
```

I feel like there is a better way.  I'm trying to use javascript over css to learn javascript.

Comment: Can't you do this entirely with css alone.? Do you require javascript for this.?

Comment: @ynos1234 I've added a CSS alternative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery, you might want to try something a bit less clumsy:

```
$(".someContent").hover( function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("highLight");

}
, function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("highLight");
});
```

And use CSS transitions (if you can) to trigger the effects:

```
.someContent {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: black;
    transition: width 0.5s, height 0.5s;
}

.highLight {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 80%;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Here is a working example: http://jsbin.com/kagesoqaca

Comment: nice that does feel smoother.  The jQuery is a function, function does the second function always get ran after when the ',' is used?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: The first function gets called when you do a mouse enter, and the second one gets called when you do a mouse out.

Answer (score 3):

You can handle transitions with css and just toggle `.highLight` class to your element when `mousenter` and `mousout`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".someContent").mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("highLight");
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("highLight");
    });
})
```

**CSS**

```
.someContent{
    background:#ff5656;
    height:60px;
    width:30%;
    opacity:0.5;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.highLight{
    width:80%;
    height: 200px;
    opacity:1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qvukpoLb/

Answer (score 1):

Your event `mouseleave` is positioned at the wrong place and you don't delete the style added by your animation.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".someContent").on("mouseenter", function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("highLight");
        if ($(this).hasClass('highLight')) {
            $(this).animate({"width": "80%", "height": "200px", "opacity": "1"}, "fast");
        } else {
            $(this).animate({"width": "30%", "height": "60px", "opacity": "1"}, "fast");
        }
    }).on("mouseleave", function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("highLight");
        $(this).removeAttr( 'style' );
    });
})
```

```css
.someContent {
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: relative;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="someContent">
  Hello
</div>
```

Comment: didn't resize the div, I think I figured it out but I don't like the repeat of code I'm using in it above

Comment: @Sam The problem is caused by your animation. It add a style on your div. I updated my answer.